# Is it possible to use an array to represent columns in SQL Server

Tags: arrays, sql-server, variables

I am trying to create a query where the column are variable

Exp

```
Declare @parm1 int ;
Declare @param2 varchar(50) ;
Declare @param3 int ;
Select Id, name, age from @table_variable
Where
Id=@param1
Name= @param2
Age=@param3
```

instead of manually typing the columns I want to select each time, I want to replace "I'd, name, age"
With an array

```
@column_array =[list of columns I want to select ]
```

The list of columns is decided automatically from a winform app with check box list in visual studio 
that is variable in length, and values 
Is that even possible?

Comment: No it is not possible , sql does not have arrays and you cannot select from variable.

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution... this leaves dynamic SQL

Comment: You can execute sql queries you build yourself...basically build a string, and execute it with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The problem with dynamic SQL here, is you'd have to pass all your input values as a `varchar`, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Simply build the SQL statement in the application code using the list of selected columns and execute the query. No need to use T-SQL for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use a variable in that way. You can however use a variable to build the statement dynamically and execute the statement like so:
The code assumes that `@col1`, `@col2` and `@table_variable` have been declared and assigned values.

```
Declare @tsql varchar(2500);

Set @tsql = ‘ select ‘;

Set @tsql += @col1 +’, ‘;

Set @tsql += @col2;

Set @tsql ‘ from @table_variable;’

Print @tsql;

Exec (@tsqll);
```